# How to get all the name of the branch merged into develop branch after a particular date?

Tags: git

I am working in a team of 18 developers in git flow workflow.
Each developer is working on their `feature` branch which is taken from `develop` branch.
we are merging the `feature` branch back to `develop` when it passes the tests, at the time of release we take a `release` branch from develop.

Is there a way to know how many branch are merged into `develop` branch from a particular date to the date `release` branch is created?

Answer (score 2):

In general, git doesn't keep information about which branches are merged into another branch, assuming you deleted the branches in question from the machine.

Looks like you can do something like this:

```
git log --oneline REV... | grep "Merge branch"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it you might have to give the scope of current release. This kind of issue I also face when the team size is quite big:

just checkout develop branch and run the command:

`git log --after="2018-08-02" --merges --name-only --decorate
--first-parent --pretty=format:%s`

This will give all the branch merged into develop form date `2018-08-02`

hope this helps!!